# Delete Woocommerce order report history

Tags: woocommerce

I'm using latest woocommerce version. I  deleted all the orders from the backend. now i want to delete order details under reports. How do i do it.? is it possible to do it from database dables? [image]

Comment: When I delete all orders, the reports are automatically cleared. WooCommerce 4.1.0 - https://pasteboard.co/J8WmlxN.jpg

Answer (score 0):

1. Select the orders you do not want in your report
2. Move them to the trash
3. Now permanently remove them from the trash
4. Clear your browser cache